# Restangular PUT request to update 2 Objects

Tags: angularjs, html, restangular

I have 2 classes on Server side.. MyClass1 and MyClass2..
Im creating a JSON object..

```
var myclass1 = {name:'xyz', id:16};  
var myclass2 = {name:'abc', id:17}
```

and using restangular..

```
Restangular.one('some url').customPUT({var1:myclass1 , var2:myclass2 });
```

Im using spring framework to create my REST Services

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someurl", method = RequestMethod.PUT) <br>
    @ResponseBody
    public void someMethod(@RequestBody MyClass1 var1, @RequestBody MyClass2 var2) {
        //some code     
    }
```

This is the scenario...
But I had read a post on stackOverflow that for 1 request body we can pass (put request) only 1 object.. If so then what is the alternate way... 
I can send MyClass2 object through request param (there is an annotation @RequestParam) 
ex. `Restangular.one('some url').customPUT({var1:myclass1 }, {}, {var2:myclass2 }, {});` 

But again this gets appended to my URL and i dont want to change my URL..

Please help. Thnx..

Comment: actually you are already sending one object not two. {var1:myclass1 , var2:myclass2 } this is the only object you send to backend.

Comment: @wickY26       Iv put the debug point on tht method but it never gets called... It gives an exception : IO Stream closed.. It works well if i want to update just one object like... Restangular.one('some url').customPUT(myclass1); But dosent work for multiple objects..

Comment: @wickY26     what i meant to say was what should i do if i need to send 2 objects?? whats the syntax that i must be using??